# How to print sign of a number in C?

Tags: c, printf, sign

While printing a number, I am trying to print its sign before the number. Is there a way to do it without the actually if...else case mentioned in the comment section of the code below.

I have tried getting the sign of the number. But I don't know how to print just the sign.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<complex.h>

void main(){
    double complex s = 3.14 + 5.14*I;
    printf("\ns is: %f + %f i", creal(s), cimag(s));
    double complex S = conj(s);
    printf("\nConjugate of s is: %f + %f i", creal(S), cimag(S));
}

/*
printf("\nConjugate of s is: %f ", creal(S))
if cimag(S) > 0
    printf("+ %f i", cimag(S))
else
    printf("- %f i", abs(cimag(S)))
*/
```

If S = 3.14 - 5.14*I, without the if...else condition, I'm expecting to get an output something like this:

```
3.14 - 5.14 i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the sign character:

```
double x = ...;
char c = signbit(x) ? '-' : '+';
```

Then use it however you want:

```
printf ("%c %f", c, fabs(x));
```

Answer (score 6):

You can just use the printf sign flag. `+`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    float f  = 1.0;
    printf("%f%+f",f,f);

    return 0;
}
```

Output

> 1.000000+1.000000

Change to -1:

> -1.000000-1.000000

If you really need the spaces, you're going to have to do something like you described:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>



void complexToString(double complex num, char * buffer){
    double imag = cimag(num);
    char sign = (imag<0) ? '-':'+';
    sprintf(buffer,"%f %c %f i",creal(num),sign,fabs(imag));
}


int main()
{

    double complex s = 3.14 + 5.14*I;
    char buffer[50];
    complexToString(s,buffer);
    printf("%s",buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

output:

> 3.140000 + 5.142000 i

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works but how to get a space between the sign and the actual number, something like this  `1.0000 - 1.0000 i`

Comment: `(imag<0)`   loses information when `imag` is -0.0.  Better to use `signbit(imag)`.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of answers from @Antoine and @yhyrcanus, the simplest way to code for space is:

```
double complex s = 3.14 - 5.14*I;        
printf("\ns is: %f %c %f i", creal(s), signbit(cimag(s)) ? '-' : '+',cabs(cimag(s)));
```

Comment: `cabs()` works fine and it even returns a double. Why do you recommend `fabs()`? I never tried it but both `fabs()` and `cabs()` returns the same result.